# Fixed Position Background - Chrome Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I've recently put together a site that uses fixed images for backgrounds with text scrolling over them.  When I'm on chrome (not any other browser), the scroll stops working between backgrounds, halts for a about a second, and continues.  I'm not sure how to fix this so any advice is appreciated.

Here's a link to the site: http://umdtamid.com/

Comment: I've tried it and it worked fine with my google chrome!! no halts.

Comment: Can you try scrolling quickly through it?

Comment: I'm using Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). Not a single problem, make sure Chrome is up to date. Also tested on FireFox, Opera, Safari as well as mobile Safari and Chrome & FireFox mobile, no issues.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because next background is not loaded and rendered until it's in the view. Your picture quality is very high, so we can notice the delay.

(Notice that it only happens once between each two backgrounds when you scroll down the first time.)

Try reducing the image size, or preload the images with CSS or javascript.

**To preload with js**

```
<script>
  bg1 = new Image();
  bg2 = new Image();
  bg3 = new Image();
  bg1.src="url here";
  bg2.src="url here";
  bg3.src="url here";
</script>
```

**To preload with CSS only**

```
body:after{
    position:absolute; z-index:-1;
    content: url(bg1.png) url(bg2.png) url(bg3.png);
}
```

Comment: How could I preload the images in CSS?

Comment: @A.Pollack I've edited the answer. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Chrome and having the same issue.
Is it perhaps possible that when you scroll something is loaded (lazy loading principle but maybe a bit different)?